# AJAX post method: Variables are not passed to target php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xhtml, post

I am trying to send two pieces of info to a php. 
1-) tent = zuzu
2-) zart = gagi

target php simply echoes what I send so that I can check if it's working. This is the javascript:

```
    function boka ()
{
var mesparam = "tent=zuzu&zart=gagi";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;} }
xmlhttp.open("POST","/mysite/oxifa/oxifat.php?tent=zuzu&zart=gagi",true); 
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", mesparam.length);
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(mesparam);
}
```

This is oxifat.php that recieves the request:

```
    <?php
echo " sign1 <br>";


echo next($_POST);
echo next($_POST);
echo next($_POST);
echo next($_POST);
echo next($_POST);
echo $_POST['tent'];
echo $_POST['zart'];
echo $_REQUEST['tent'];
echo $_REQUEST['zart'];

echo "<br> sign2";

?>
```

As you can see I've included all sorts of things to echo out whatever is in $_POST but apparently there is nothing there and this is the response I get:

sign1

Notice: Undefined index: tent in C:\wamp\www\mysite\oxifa/oxifat.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: zart in C:\wamp\www\mysite\oxifa/oxifat.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: tent in C:\wamp\www\mysite\oxifa/oxifat.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: zart in C:\wamp\www\mysite\oxifa/oxifat.php on line 19

sign2

three lines about the "setRequestHeader" are in comment status. If I include them, I don't even get sign1. No response. What I figure out from this is everything is OK but I don't seem to understand how to use the post method to pass data to php. How do I do this? I have read everything on the net. I only do not know what "setRequestHeader" is for. One more thing: If I put ?tent=zuzu&zart=gagi at the end of target URL, $_REQUEST thing works. But that's GET and not what I'm trying to do. What is the $_POST's deal?

Comment: Found out the problem finally. H's in xmlHttp.setRequestHeader are capital and they've been destroying my code. Now made them small and it works. Never imagined it could be case sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to invoke following code

```
function getXMLObject() {
  var xmlHttp = false;
  try {
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");// For Old Microsoft Browsers
  }
  catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// For Microsoft IE 6.0+
    }
    catch (e2) {
      xmlHttp = false;// No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
    }
  }
  if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();//For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
  }
  return xmlHttp;// Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();//xmlhttp holds the ajax object

//use this method for asynchronous communication
function doRequest(params, callback) {
  if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "your_script.php?" + params, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        else {
          alert("Error retrieving information (status = " + xmlhttp.status + ")\n" + response);
        }
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
}
```

and in your PHP script first thing off write

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: I put two links that shoot getXMLObject() and doRequest respectively. I replaced "your_script.php?" and params. I replaced callback with where I want the response to appear and I put print_r($_POST); in my php file. This is what I get: Array ( )

Comment: xmlhttp.send(); I put all the variables inside this. I do not have any other form or anything to fill $_POST. As far as I understand from my search xmlhttp.send() is enough to pass things to php but in this case $_POST turns out to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the parameters with the URL which is for GET, not the right way for POST.

See: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Try taking the parameters off in the request here:

xmlhttp.open("POST","/mysite/oxifa/oxifat.php?tent=zuzu&zart=gagi",true);

And then uncommenting these:

//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", mesparam.length);
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

Comment: I've seen that link. It's everywhere. I don't pass the parameters with URL. I put ?tent=zuzu&zart=gagi at the end of URL just to experiment hoping to find out what was wrong. $_REQUEST works when I do that. I forgot to remove it when I was pasting it here. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment those 2 lines, otherwise you the php `$_POST` is not going to pick it up. also, as stonemonkey77 answered, you are also passing the parameters in the get url.

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", mesparam.length);
```

Comment: When I uncomment those lines, I get nothing. Looks like Javascript doesn't run when those lines are on. I believe the problem is something to do with those lines. I am using some wrong variable or the like. But than again I don't understand the "setRequestHeader" thing.